# Spribg boot при запросе в PostMapping выдает ошибку 403

Tags: java, spring-boot, jackson, jpql

[При запросе PostMapping в ReportController,должен сформировать выборку по запросу из EmployeeRepository в БД и вернуть в метод generatedStatisticReported, но возвращается ошибку 403]https://github.com/AlexB986/file-jpa.git

Comment: Ошибка 403 у вас возвращается потому что вы настроили ExceptionHandler с Exception. Соответственно любое исключение у вас будет выдавать 403 ошибку - HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN.

Comment: Спасибо исправил. Но проблема еще и в запросе @Query я думаю она в основном не формирует правильно запрос из за чего вылетает ошибка.
    @Query("SELECT new ru.skypro.lessons.springboot.JPAS.JPAS.dto.ReportDTO(  "p.role 
            ,COUNT(e.id) 
           ,MAX(e.salary) 
           ,MIN(e.salary) 
           ,AVG(e.salary)) " 
            "FROM Employee e join  position p GROUP BY p.id")
    List<ReportDTO> statisticReported();

Comment: сделал Пул реквест к вашей ветке с исправлениями. Единственно - пост переделал на гет, потому что мне так тестить проще было ))